# Preserve underline status of text for later restoration

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm writing a module that should store a content control's (CC) `Range.Text` before 1) replacing it with some nonbreaking spaces and 2) setting its `Range.Font.Underline` to `wdUnderlineSingle`. (`Case 2` in the following code.)

Later, the CC is restored to its original state. (`Case 3` in the code.)

Assume the original text contains a mixture of underlined and non-underlined text. How would I ensure that I restore not just the text value, but its mix of underline attributes?

Here's part of the code:

```
' Code before omitted
          For Each oCC In oRngStory.ContentControls
            Select Case lngAction
              Case 1
                oCount = oCount + 1
              Case 2
                oCount = oCount + 1
                ' CC inside body text: replace text value with 30 nonbreaking spaces
                If LCase(oCC.Tag) = "body text" Then
                    ' Store existing text
                    arrText(i) = oCC.Range.Text
                    ' Temporarily replace text with 30 nonbreaking spaces
                    oCC.Range.Text = String(30, ChrW(160))
                    ' Underline text
                    oCC.Range.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
                End If
                i = i + 1
              Case 3
                oCount = oCount + 1
                If LCase(oCC.Tag) = "body text" Then
                    ' Restore existing text
                    oCC.Range.Text = arrText(i)
                    ' ### HOW TO RESTORE EXISTING TEXT'S UNDERLINE STATE?
                End If
                i = i + 1
            End Select
          Next oCC
' Code after omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use a custom undo record. For example:

```
Dim objUndo As UndoRecord
Set objUndo = Application.UndoRecord
With objUndo
  If .IsRecordingCustomRecord = False Then
  .StartCustomRecord ("Demo")
    For Each oCC In oRngStory.ContentControls
    With oCC
      If LCase(.Tag) = "body text" Then
        ' Temporarily replace text with 30 nonbreaking spaces
        .Range.Text = String(30, ChrW(160))
      End If
    End With
  Next oCC
  'insert whatever further processing you want to perform here
  .EndCustomRecord
End With
ActiveDocument.Undo
```

With this approach, your temporary changes are automatically undone once they're finished with.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store formatting in a text variable. Instead, you might hide/unhide the text, employing something along the lines of:

```
Dim oCC As ContentControl, oRngStory As Range, Rng As Range
Dim lngAction As Long, oCount As Long
...
          For Each oCC In oRngStory.ContentControls
            oCount = oCount + 1
            With oCC
              If LCase(.Tag) = "body text" Then
                Select Case lngAction
                Case 2
                  ' Replace text value with 30 nonbreaking spaces
                  Set Rng = .Range
                    With Rng
                      ' Temporarily replace visible text with 30 nonbreaking spaces
                      .InsertBefore String(30, ChrW(160))
                      .Start = .Start + 30
                      .Font.Hidden = True
                      ' Underline text
                      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
                      .Start = .Start - 30
                      .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
                    End With
                    i = i + 1
                Case 3
                  ' Restore original text
                  Set Rng = .Range
                  With Rng
                    .End = .Start + 30
                    .Text = vbNullString
                  End With
                  .Range.Font.Hidden = False
                End Select
              End If
            End With
          Next oCC
```

Of course, if underlining is the only special font attribute and it applies to all of the content control's content, you could just underline the entire content control so that no underlining code is needed:

```
  For Each oCC In oRngStory.ContentControls
    oCount = oCount + 1
    With oCC
      If LCase(.Tag) = "body text" Then
        Select Case lngAction
          Case 2
            arrText(i) = oCC.Range.Text
            ' Temporarily replace text with 30 nonbreaking spaces
            .Range.Text = String(30, ChrW(160))
          Case 3
            oCC.Range.Text = arrText(i)
        End Select
        i = i + 1
      End If
    End With
  Next oCC
```

Comment: Thanks for those creative suggestions. I will implement your "hide existing text" solution.

On a more general note, is it possible to copy a content control's .Range to a variable defined as a range, then later copy it back? Would that copy every property inside .Range? And what about .Range.FormattedText?

Comment: Yes, it is quite easy to store a content control's .Range to a variable defined as a range, but overwriting that content control's .Range defeats the purpose, because what you're storing is the range, not its content. There is no data type into which you can store and retrieve formatted text, regardless of whether you use the FormattedText property. You could use a temporary document for that, however.